# find code with no returns

Tags: sql

i have a table with the following columns

```
Code    week_Num    week_day   return
234234     1          1          0
423443     1          2          0
234234     1          3          0 
996434     1          4          0  
444234     1          5          0  
234234     1          6          0  
234234     1          7          0  
423423     2          1          0  
234234     2          2          1  
686433     2          3          2  
234234     2          4          0  
225257     2          5          3  
234234     2          6          0  
and so on...
```

I need to find all codes that have had no returns in a week.
week_num column is the week number, and week_day column is:

```
1 = monday
2 = tuesday
3 = wednesday
```

and so on..

Answer (score 4):

You can use aggregation:

```
select code, week_num
from t
group by code, week_num
having max(return) = 0;
```